# Java regular expression for digits and dashes

Tags: java, regex, digits

I need a regular expression which matches lines with only 4(four) hyphens and 13 digits(0-9). The order is undefined.
I have regex like:

```
^([0-9\u2013-]{17})$
```

But, when I receive strings as

```
----123456789---- or 1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9
```

matching is true but it must be false for me.

Could you please explain what I need use in order to matches were only with strings like `123-345-565-45-67 or 123-1-34-5435-45- or ----1234567890123 etc?`

Comment: You may try `s.matches"(?s)(?=(?:[^-]*-){4}[^-]*$)(?=(?:\\D*\\d){13}\\D*$).*"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
^(?=(?:[^-]*-){4}[^-]*$)(?=(?:\D*\d){13}\D*$).*$
```

**[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/9Befb0/1)**

**Explanation:**

- `^` - asserts the start of the line
- `(?=(?:[^-]*-){4}[^-]*$)` - positive lookahead to make sure that there are only 4 occurrences of `-` present in the string
- `(?=(?:\D*\d){13}\D*$)` - positive lookahead to make sure that there are 13 occurrences of a digit present in the string
- `.*` - once the above 2 lookaheads are satisified, match 0+ occurrences of any character except a newline character
- `$` - asserts the end of the line

Escape `\` with another `\` in JAVA

Comment: It looks like what I need. Thanks

Comment: Note: You do not need initial `^` and `$` in a `matches` method. Without a DOTALL modifier, this pattern will not match multiline strings.

Comment: I didn't know about it. Thanks for the info.